# how to implement the following style/customize the toolbar in iphone applicaiton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, toolbar, tabbar, customization

1. I want to change my common toolbar style to this style..
   [image]
2. Transparent toolbar.
3. the round conner at the left and right side.
4. press any of them have the click events. (all of them have already implemented in the old toolbar version.)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just write your own custom view. You can use an image for the background and then use a set of uibuttons and customize to your hearts content. It'll be easier than customizing the toolbar.

Comment: YES...well,,I have to implement the badgeValue, set the tile. and a lot of things....